# GoogleMap API ズームレベルについて

Tags: google-maps

GoogleMap APIを使用してページに地図を表示させています。
mapOptionsのzoomで小数点を設定することはできるのでしょうか？

mapOptionsでのzoomの設定を変更する際に'17.5'のような小数を入れても、実際にはサイズが'18'になり、ブラウザのコンソール画面に、map.getZoom()を表示させても'18'となってしまいます。
Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Referenceを読んでも、

> setZoom(zoom:number)

としか書いておらず、小数点が使用できるのかわからないです。

ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ja#MapOptions

MapOptions object specification

> zoom
>
> Type:  number The initial Map zoom level. Required. Valid values:
>   Integers between zero, and up to the supported maximum zoom level.

リファレンスを見る限り、整数のようです。小数点を付けるべきではないでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
やはり整数のみなのですね...